# Assign integer value to char string in C++

Tags: c++

I want to assign an integer value to a string of character like assigning integer 5 to "learning".

Comment: could you please provide a pseudocode for this situation? i can't really understand what you want to do..

Comment: 'Assigning integer 5 to "learning"' doesn't make any sense - please ask a decent question that actually allows people to provide meaningful answers. Also, please refrain from telling people how urgent your questions are, especially when asking such basic questions - the people on this site are volunteers answering your question in their spare time, so please respect that.

Comment: -1 for "my other codes".  I frickin' **hate** this expression.  It could be Code, or Program... but never, ever "Codes".  Ugh.

Comment: Maybe don't use *slang* either... "coz" doesn't seem to me like an English word. :) Many programmers don't have American English as their mother tongue :)

Comment: You don't assign to values, you assign to variables. E.g. `int learning; learning = 5;`

Answer (score 5):

You mean like:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
...
std::map<int, std::string> myMap;
myMap[5] = "learning";
```

?

Comment: @kenny: he/she speaks about the number 5, not the string containing a "5".

Comment: it might be more apropriate to have "MyMap["learning"] = 5;" to assign 5 to "learning", but the question is vague, so who knows...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
std::map<std::string, int> myMap;

myMap["learning"] = 5;
```